# vert.x Serve static files

Tags: java, vert.x

I have the following Verticle class:

```
public class SendFileExample extends AbstractVerticle {

  public void start(Future<Void> fut) throws Exception {
      Router router = Router.router(vertx);
      router.route("/hello").handler(StaticHandler.create("client"));

      router.route("/hello").handler(routingContext -> {
          HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
          System.out.println("Hello");
          response.sendFile("client/index.html");
      });

      vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(3000,
          result -> {
              if (result.succeeded()) {
                  fut.complete();
              } else {
                  fut.fail(result.cause());
              }
          }
      );
  }
}
```

My html file is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> hello </title>
</heade>
<body>
    <h1> Hello World </h1>
    <button> Hello </button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I used "StaticHandler.create..." in order to serve all static files inside client folder.
As you can understand, I want that once the server gets a GET request to "localhost:3000/hello", the client will get an HTML page, which will call app.js file.

Unfortunately, I can't do it. index.html is loaded and the browser can't load app.js.

It's important to note that index.html and app.js both are located exactly in the same path which is ${PROJECT_ROOT}/client.

The code, however, is located in: 
${PROJECT_ROOT}/src/main/java/com/company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try something straight-forward like:

```
 if (req.path().equals("/")) {
   res.sendFile("client/index.html");
 }else{
   res.sendFile( "client" + req.path() );
 }
```

Comment: print out the paths and see if they match to your file. You can also check the files' existence

Comment: `System.out.println( "path = " + req.path() );`

Comment: try without the router. a plain handler you had before

Comment: This works but the right way to do this is to use the static handler for all paths starting with "/hello". See Alexey's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You simply missed the star sign when you defined your static handler:

```
router.route("/hello*").handler(StaticHandler.create("client"));
```